# how to crop my image as shown below image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am very new to android ,I am trying to display my image as shown below,but my my image is not coming up properly.Please help me out in solving this problem.

[click here for image i need like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7fxQ.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need rectangular image ??

Comment: i need below image curve shape@praval sharma

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate on how it should look. Your link shows a rectangular image, so your comment of a curve shape is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use scaleType tag in your layout like this example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

More information about scaleType can be found here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: in need curve shape below my image like my attachment@gorio

Comment: You can Use  below UIL

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new       ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(thisContext    
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()).build();
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10)) //rounded corner bitmap
.cacheInMemory(true)
  .cacheOnDisc(true)
 .build();
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
imageLoader.displayImage(image_url,image_view, options );
```

Comment: try this if you wnat to use UIL for round courners